# VB.NET hide taskbar icon of an external application using win32 api

Tags: vb.net, winapi, taskbar

In my project I need to hide the icon of an external application from taskbar. I am able to fetch appropriate window handle using **FindWindow** method in **user32.dll**

Is there any function to hide taskbar icon, something like:

> HideTaskbarIcon (hwnd as IntPtr)

I have found the following code on google but can't understand the operators, can someone elaborate the operators used and their equivalent in visual basic:

```
long style= GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE);
style &= ~(WS_VISIBLE);    // this works - window become invisible 

style |= WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW;   // flags don't work - windows remains in taskbar
style &= ~(WS_EX_APPWINDOW); 

ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE); // hide the window
SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, style); // set the style
ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW); // show the window for the new style to come into effect
ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE); // hide the window so we can't see it
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any function to hide taskbar icon, something like:
>
> ```
> HideTaskbarIcon (hwnd as IntPtr)
> ```

No.

> I have found the following code on google but can't understand the operators

Window styles are expressed as a bitmask.  The code in question is using bitwise `AND`, `NOT`, and `OR` operators to manipulate the individual bits.  It uses `GetWindowLong()` to retrieve the window's existing style bits, removes the `WS_VISIBLE` and `WS_EX_APPWINDOW` bits, adds the `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW` bit, and then assigns the new bitmask back to the window.  Only visible windows with the `WS_EX_APPWINDOW` bit can appear on the Taskbar.

That being said, the original code is wrong.  *Extended* window styles (ones with `_EX_` in their names) cannot be retrieved/assigned using `GWL_STYLE`, `GWL_EXSTYLE` must be used instead, and there is no reason to ever manipulate `WS_VISIBLE` directly as `ShowWindow()` handles that.  The original code should have looked like this instead:

```
LONG style = GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);

style |= WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW;
style &= ~WS_EX_APPWINDOW; 

ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE);
SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, style);
ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE);
```

> can someone elaborate the operators used and their equivalent in visual basic

Microsoft has documentation on that topic:

[Logical and Bitwise Operators in Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz3k228a.aspx)

[Logical/Bitwise Operators (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2h9cz2eb.aspx)

For example:

```
Dim hWnd as IntPtr = ...
Dim style as Integer = GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE)

style = style or WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW
style = style and not WS_EX_APPWINDOW

ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE)
SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, style)
ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW)
ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE);
```

Comment: style variable must be a long otherwise it will give overflow message

Comment: Not if you PInvoke `(Get|Set)WindowLong()` to use `Integer` values.  `(Get|Set)WindowLong()` operate on 32bit values, but `Long` is 64bit. [How to use GetWindowLong properly in VB.NET](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/how-to-use-getwindowlong-properly-in-vb-net.1312789/)